# OPTIMIZE TABLE seems to "lock" tables (innodb)

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

During executing an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on big tables the process seems to "lock" the tables. Is there something you can do to speed up the process or prevent it from "locking" the tables?

The application/service timeout while executing `OPTIMIZE TABLE`

`mysql 5.7.36`

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
port                           = 3306
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000
skip_name_resolve
sql_mode                       = STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO
sysdate_is_now                 = 1
symbolic_links                 = 0

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
server_id                      = 1
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days               = 10
sync_binlog                    = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators= 1
binlog_format                  = ROW
master_verify_checksum         = 1

# REPLICATION #
gtid_mode                      = ON
enforce_gtid_consistency

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 64M
max_heap_table_size            = 64M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 0
max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method                 = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group           = 2
innodb_log_file_size                = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size              = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit      = 1
innodb_file_per_table               = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size             = 40G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances        = 12
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode            = 2

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time                = 1
```

Comment: After the `OPTIMIZE` is complete, you have probably seen a message saying that InnoDB doesn’t support that feature, so the table was recreated. This effectively creates a new table, copies the data, then drops the old table. Locking is a requirement.

Answer (score 6):

The answer from Rick James is very wrong and misleading, so I felt the need to provide a different one.

Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html for requirements for executing this statement without locking the tables. From that page:

> OPTIMIZE TABLE uses online DDL for **regular and partitioned** InnoDB tables, which reduces downtime for concurrent DML operations. The table rebuild triggered by OPTIMIZE TABLE is completed in place. **An exclusive table lock is only taken briefly during the prepare phase and the commit phase of the operation**. During the prepare phase, metadata is updated and an intermediate table is created. During the commit phase, table metadata changes are committed.

> OPTIMIZE TABLE rebuilds the table using the table copy method under the following conditions:

> When the old_alter_table system variable is enabled.

> When the server is started with the --skip-new option.

> OPTIMIZE TABLE using online DDL is not supported for InnoDB tables that contain FULLTEXT indexes. The table copy method is used instead.

I can confirm that using the correct configuration (such as the default AWS MySQL 5.7 Aurora configuration) allows executing `OPTIMIZE TABLE` with no noticeable table locks.

And lastly, it's very easy to find valid use cases for using `OPTIMIZE TABLE` - we just had one recently where a bug prevented a cron job from deleting old data, and once it was fixed the table had several hundred GB of allocated and unused space, for which we would have to pay our cloud DB provider. `OPTIMIZE TABLE` removed all of that allocated unused space.

Comment: Just adding my support for your comment. The MySQL docs themselves offer guidance for when it might be appropriate to use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and just saying not to do it is wrong. Additionally, if you have a full text index on a table with many deletions not only does optimizing it decrease the index storage space it can also massively improve FTS performance.

Answer (score 0):

True.  `OPTIMIZE TABLE` locks the table.  But there is essentially no reason to "optimize" an InnoDB table.  Simply don't do it.

Comment: Why? After `OPTIMIZE TABLE` the database is smaller in size

Comment: @clarkk - And, as you do more writes -- even just Updates -- the size will grow again.  Unless you are doing massive deletes and not re-inserting an equivalent number of rows, `OPTIMIZE` shrinks the table only temporarily.